# Detect re-use the same names in children scopes

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a rule to detect when the same variable name redeclared in children scopes, which might be confusing?

For example:

```js
{
  const myVar = "ok"
  if (true)
  {
    //should give warning because myVar already declared in parent scope
    const myVar = "not ok";
    console.log(myVar);
  }
  console.log(myVar);
}
```

[`no-redeclare`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-redeclare) doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

[no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow):

> Disallow variable declarations from shadowing variables declared in
> the outer scope
>
> Shadowing is the process by which a local variable shares the same
> name as a variable in its containing scope. For example:
>
> ```
> var a = 3;
> function b() {
>     var a = 10;
> }
> ```